# I'm trying to understand how to use promises in javascript, but my script never executes the "Then"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, promise

I have a script that sets a set number of usernames, and then for each username, runs a fetch request to twitches API endpoint to get the Json information for each user. I then wanted to put that information into an array for later use, and found out I had to use promises, which I never worked with before. I read through this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises and this: https://github.com/domenic/promises-unwrapping/blob/master/docs/states-and-fates.md and I read Felix Kling response here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and I'm still having trouble understanding exactly what goes where and what does what. This is what I have so far:

```
var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]

var arr = [];

var headers = {
  'Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}

var promise = new Promise(function usersJson(callback) {
  for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=" + users[i];
    fetch(url, {headers})
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
      arr.push(myJson);
    })
    callback(arr);
  };
})

promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
})
```

and from what I understand, this should be running through each endpoint, pushing the data to my array variable, and then once the whole things is "fulfilled" it should call the 'then' thing with my promise variable to console.log my array. All I get is a blank array and I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong. If I put the console.log(arr) in after the arr.push(json), I get 8 arrays returned, each with the next response body tacked on, so I know the call is working, I just can't get it to stick in my array.

Comment: Why use a for loop when a forEach will do?

Comment: You’re also not returning anything in promise.

Comment: no, actually your ```callback(arr);``` should be inside the 2nd ```then```, and also each fetch is a promise, so once you resolve the firstone it will trigger the ```callback(arr)``` and will get out

Comment: I just switched it to a forEach, and that doesn't solve my problem. So far as I can tell it doesn't matter whether you use forEach or a for loop.

Comment: you're calling `callback(arr);` before the promise executes

Comment: I'm confused, so if I put the callback in the second one, then I only get the one thing added to my array. How do I get them all added to the array?

Comment: @Cdhippen fetch returns a promise for you, so you don't need to wrap the fetch call with a "promise executor", see my answer. Wrap the fetch call in a function, not a promise executor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that may help you to think more in promises is that once you're in promise-land you can only get the data while you're still in promise-land. In your example, you're getting the data from the `fetch` promise. That means that you can only use that data from inside of the `fetch` promise. Notice here:

```
.then(function(myJson) {
  arr.push(myJson);
})
callback(arr);
```

The `arr.push` where you're building the array is *inside* the promise, but `callback(arr)` is *outside*. Since you're not inside the promise anymore you can't get the data.

In your case you also want to wait on multiple promises simultaneously since you're fetching data from multiple sources at once. The best way to do this would be to use `Promise.all` and an array of promises:

```
const promise = Promise.all(users.map(user => {
    const url = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=${user}`;
    return fetch(url, { headers })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    });
}));
```

Now `promise.then` will give you access to an array of the data once all the promises have resolved. You don't need to push to another array, the `.map` will create the array of promises for you.

---

You can also write this using the `async` / `await` syntax which is easier to reason about and potentially cleaner.

```
const promise = Promise.all(users.map(async user => {
    const url = `https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=${user}`;
    const response = await fetch(url, { headers });
    return response.json();
}));
```

---

By the way, you should only need to use `new Promise` when working with libraries that don't implement promises themselves. `fetch` already returns a Promise, so when you call it you're already getting a promise back so there's no need to wrap it with `new Promise`.

Comment: This is an amazing explanation, thank you very much. I was able to get the console.log working with this information, and I should be able to move forward from here. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To get the result you want, your code can be rewritten as

```
const users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]

const headers = {
  'Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}

Promise.all(users.map(user => fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=${user}`, {headers}).then(response => response.json())))
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

A little more readable

```
const users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"]

const headers = {
  'Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}

const mapper = user => 
    fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=${user}`, {headers})
    .then(response => response.json());

const promises = users.map(mapper);

Promise.all(promises)
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

and, finally, since your original code shows no knowledge of ES2015+

```
var users = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

var headers = {
    'Client-Id': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
};

var mapper = function mapper(user) {
    return fetch("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=" + user, { headers: headers }).then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    });
};

var promises = users.map(mapper);

Promise.all(promises).then(function (result) {
    return console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I'd say it's a fair trade

Comment: Well, better is your opinion, @AlexanderMills. Perhaps you've explained more, but your non async/await code is very wrong ... `Array#map` does not return a promise, therefore `runTheTrap(users).then` will complain that `.then` is not a function :p

Comment: that's true I fixed it mucho upvoto now? don't make me retract my upvote lol

Answer (score 0):

do something like this instead:

```
const runTheTrap = async function(users){
   const ret = [];
   for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=" + users[i];
    await fetch(url, {headers})
    .then(function(r) {
      return r.json().then(v => ret.push(v));
    });
  };

  return ret;
}


runTheTrap(users).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

but frankly async/await is kinda 'tarded, I prefer this approach:

```
     const runTheTrap = function(users){
        return users.map(function(u){
          var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=" + u;
          return fetch(url, {headers}).then(r => {
              return r.json();
          });
      }



      Promise.all(runTheTrap(users)).then(function(vals){
          // you have your vals
       });
```

Comment: `I prefer this approach` - except, you're returning an array ... and an array has no `.then` method, so, your preferred approach is flawed

Comment: yeah whoops let me fix